# About Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In file `readFile.js`, function `readFile()` is defined as below:

```
function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(!fs.existsSync(path)) {
            console.log('Will throw error now!');
            reject("memes.json file does not exist");
        }
        else {
            //File exists
            console.log('File found');
            var data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
            resolve(data);
        }
    })
}

module.exports.readFile = readFile;
```

In file `getImage.js`, `targetImage` is defined as below:

```
var targetImage = data.readFile(path)
    .then(function(value) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(value);

        for(let i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
            if(jsonData[i].title == memeImage) {
                console.log('Visit URL: ', jsonData[i].image);
                return jsonData[i].image;
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Encountered some error during reading file');
        return 'Errored out :(';
    });

module.exports = targetImage;
```

Finally, file `modifyImage.js` simply has:

```
console.log('Output: ', targetImageValue);
```

When I run the above program as `node ./lib/modifyImage.js -n Determined`, I get the following output:

> File found
> Output:  Promise {  }
> Visit URL:  http://example.com/pqr.png

My question is - why do I get: `Output:  Promise { <pending> }`?  I am following [the example here](https://2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html#example%3A-promisifying-xmlhttprequest), so I expect the promise is getting fulfilled in `readFile()` when I call `reject()` and `resolve()`.  I think I am *consuming* the promise using `.then()` in `getImage.js`. Why does the program say promise is still pending?  What am I missing?

Comment: The `targetImage` you export is a Promise. So assuming you have `let targetImageValue = require('getImage.js')` then it has to be `targetImageValue.then(value => { console.log('Output: ', value); });`

Comment: `var targetImage = data.readFile(path).then(...` means that `targetImage` will be a Promise that resolves once that `.then` runs. To use it elsewhere, you need to call `.then` on it as well

Comment: @t.niese, how is `targetImage` a promise?  In the example at the link posted, is he creating a promise when he uses `httpGet()` below?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, in the example link posted, when the author does `httpGet('http://example.com/file.txt') .then( function (value) { console.log('Contents: ' + value); }, function (reason) { console.error('Something went wrong', reason); })`, is he again creating a promise?

Comment: Yes, every time you call `.then` on something that's a Promise, you create another Promise. If that `httpGet(..).then` was saved to a variable, you'd have to call `.then` on it to run code when it resolves

Comment: `data.readFile(path)` returns a Promise. On that Promise you call `.then()` the `then` function itself returns another Promise. On that Promise you call `catch()` and that catch also Returns a Promise, and that final Promise is then saved in `targetImage`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it helps.  Thank you. :)

Comment: @t.niese, it is helpful.  Thank you! :)

Comment: Additional notes: **1.** Doing a `fs.existsSync(path)` before a `fs.readFileSync` does not protect you from the case that `fs.readFileSync` does not find any file. Another process could delete the file between the  `fs.existsSync(path)`  check and the `fs.readFileSync` call. So you need to handle the _"file does not exist"_ error case for the `fs.readFileSync` directly. And if you do that you can get rid of the `fs.existsSync(path)`. **2.** wrapping a completely synchronous code into a `new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ })` does not make to much sense.

Comment: @t.niese, yes, what you say makes sense to me.  Both the things I am doing are absurd.  I will rectify them shortly.  Thanks again!